# Count lines in file without counting empty lines

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Let's say there is a file with 7 lines in it.
Eg:

```
a
b
c
#

d
e
```

When I run `grep -c '#' -c -v filenamehere`
it gives me 6 lines.

I want it to show 5 lines to take away that blank space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your file has *seven* lines in it, but you want to count lines that are non-empty and that do not start with `#`.

```
$ grep -c '^[^#]' file
5
```

This counts the number of lines that contain a character at the start that is not a `#` character.

The expression `[^#]` matches a single character that is not `#`.  The full expression `^[^#]` matches a non-`#` at the start of a line.

Empty lines don't match this expression, and neither do lines that start with `#`¹.

If you just want to count non-empty lines:

```
$ grep -c '.' file
6
```

This counts lines that contain at least one character.

---

For completeness, to count empty lines:

```
$ grep -c -v '.' file
1
```

To count lines that are empty or that starts with `#`:

```
$ grep -c -v '^[^#]' file
2
```

---

Note that both `-c` and `-v` are "global" options.  They change the behavior of the whole `grep` operation when they are given on the command line.  It does not make sense to specify `-c` or `-v` multiple times, and they don't take option-arguments.

Also note that if you specify the pattern or regular expression anywhere other than as the first argument after all options, then use `-e 'pattern'` so that `grep` knows that this is the pattern that you are search with.  That is, use either

```bsh
grep -e '.' -c -v file
```

or

```bsh
grep -c -e '.' -v file
```

or

```bsh
grep -c -v '.' file
```

GNU `grep` will rearrange the command line in such a way that options come before pathname operands (unless `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set in the environment), but you generally want to write portable shell code that work with any `grep` implementation.

---

<sup>¹ lines that start with a non-character (a sequence of bytes that happens not to form a valid character in the user's locale charmap) would also be excluded in most `grep` implementations. You can use `LC_ALL=C grep` to work around that. That should be a valid thing to do as `#` is part of the portable character set so should be invariant across locales on a given system.</sup>

Comment: bro any idea how i can do the same for perl scripting

Comment: @WenhanXiao From the command line, there's no real need to use Perl for this as `grep` would do the work far quicker (or at least easier). To do it from within a Perl script, you would have to ask on the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site, as it's a generic programming question and not really specific to Unix, and therefore off-topic on this particular site.

Comment: @WenhanXiao This could be something to start from: [Perl: Erase empty lines and save in a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14365371)

Comment: *The right thing* in `grep -c '#' -c` would be to count the number of lines that contain `#` in the `-c` file, and that's what all POSIX compliant implementations do. The problem is that GNU `grep` is the implementation found on most systems these days (or a fork or rewrite on some recent BSDs), and GNU `grep` doesn't do that unless there's a POSIXLY_CORRECT variable in the environment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I updated that part of the text.